# How to inject HttpContext in .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection

I am using Unity as my IoC for my .NET Framework 4.7.2 web application. I need to inject HttpContext. How can I do that?

Comment: It should already by available out of the box. Why would you want to inject it again?

Comment: I need to inject it in the data access layer

Comment: Even there, you can access it directly. If you don't want to do that, pass a reference into your DAL class in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

As you've tagged this as `asp.net` I assume you mean Asp.Net Classic and not Asp.Net Core.

Asp.Net was written without consideration to dependency Injection. Instead, it relies on dependency resolution through thread local/execution context aware storage. So you should be able to access the current `HttpContext` from anywhere using `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: You are right. It is. Net Framework and not. Net Core. In. Net Core, I am able to do that using IHttpAccessor. In. Net Framework 4.7.2 they introduced the Dependency Injection

Comment: Ok, you're on .NET Framework, but what version of asp.net are you using? Classic or Asp.Net Core?

Comment: please ready my question well, it is Class .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But there are to web frameworks that can be run on the .NET Framework. Asp.NET and Asp.NET Core. Which of them do you use?